# How to do enumerations in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 2 I know of a few plugins for enumerations such as acts_as_enumeration and enumerate_by but they don't seem to be maintained or updated for Rails 3. Preferably, the solution would store the enum in memory rather than a database for performance reasons but really any method would be useful since it can always be cached.

I did find [enumerated_attribute](http://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) that claims to work with Rails 3 but quite honestly I don't like the API and was hoping for another good solution.

(Sorry for only linking to the one plugin but it won't let me post more than one link until I get a higher reputation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently using lwe's [simple_enum](http://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) which seems to be actively developed and stores values on memory or if you prefer on a table.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply... I haven't had a chance to dive into writing the code yet for this project but this looks like a pretty good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataMapper as your ORM have a look at [dm-types](http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types) which includes an Enum type.

Answer (score 0):

There is this gem, [enumerate_it](https://github.com/cassiomarques/enumerate_it), it has good documentation and very well done!